# Implementing GoogleInteractiveMediaAds in tvOS and encountering 'IMAAdDisplayContainer's adContainerViewController property is nil' error

Tags: swift, ads, ott

I try to implement GoogleInteractiveMediaAds and every time this delegate method is called ("failedWith adErrorData: IMAAdLoadingErrorData!")

I print the error in my console I am getting this line Error loading ads: Optional("Ads cannot be requested because the IMAAdDisplayContainer's adContainerViewController property is nil.")

Here is my code

```
func requestAdsViaSDK(OnView : UIView){
self.currentView.isHidden = false
setUpAdsLoader()
var prerollTag = ""
prerollTag = self.addRandomNumber(dfpUrl as String)
print("Preroll tag",prerollTag)
let adDisplayContainer = IMAAdDisplayContainer(adContainer: OnView, viewController:   self.episodeController)
let request = IMAAdsRequest(
adTagUrl: prerollTag,
adDisplayContainer: adDisplayContainer,
contentPlayhead: contentPlayhead,
userContext: nil)
adsLoader?.requestAds(with: request)
}

func setUpAdsLoader() {
print("adsLoader==================================)")
adsLoader = IMAAdsLoader(settings: nil)
adsLoader!.delegate = self
}

func addRandomNumber(\_ str:String)-\>String{
let randomNumber = arc4random()
let getFullDfp = "(str)(randomNumber)"
return getFullDfp
}
```

Comment: I see the same error, did you manage to fix this? How?